# Convert HTTP JSON response to R data frame

Tags: rest, httpresponse, webapi, griddb

I am using a web API to run my SQL queries on a GridDb instance.
GridDB's web API sends query responses in JSON Array format.
e.g.

```
[{\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"Column_1\",\"type\":\"FLOAT\"},{\"name\":\"Column_2\",\"type\":\"FLOAT\"}], 
\"results\":[[137.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[50.0,16.0],[40.0,0.0],[100.0,22.0],
[0.0,111.0],[0.0,1452.0],[0.0,706.0],[100.0,982.0],[100.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,277.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,302.0],[100.0,60.0],[0.0,767.0],[0.0,344.0],[0.0,642.0],[0.0,0.0],[100.0,14.0],[0.0,0.0],[250.0,0.0],[75.0,1600.0],[0.0,1176.0],[100.0,283.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[50.0,0.0]]}]"
```

Now, I want to convert this JSON Array into a R dataframe and run some machine learning algorithms over it.
I want my data in the following format :-

Column_1           Column_2
137.0                0.0
0.0                  0.0
50.0                 16.0
........

I used this program, but its not giving desired results.

```
qr1 <- POST ( my_query_url, 
   add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8" ) ,      
   config = authenticate("***", "***"), 
   body = query_request_body 
   ) 
interim_data <- rjson::fromJSON(toString(qr1),  simplify=TRUE)
interim_data_frame <- as.data.frame(interim_data)
```

But its not giving desired reults, and all the data inside interim_data_frame is a single string.
Can you give me some idea how to convert a HTTPS response object in JSON Array format, to a data frame or tibble in R.

Thanks